# Getting message to upgrade my version of Chromium but when when I try to upgrade it says I already have latest version

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, chromium

Whenever I open up a page to my gmail account I get a yellow bar at the top of the browser with this message:

> This version of Chrome is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a
>   [supported browser](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6557?hl=en). Dismiss

When I click on the "supported browser" link in the message above Im directed to a general google Chrome support page which has nothing to do with the Chromium browser.

When I try to update it the regular way I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
[sudo] password for jmarbas:
Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Done chromium-browser is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Why do I keep getting that message telling me to upgrade to the latest version if I am already at the latest available version?

I'm seeing this on Raspbian Jessie 8.0 and Chromium browser version 51.

---

EDIT(Feb 17, 2017):

I am now getting the message that the chromium-browser is "kept back" when I try to upgrade, which means that very recenty after my question was posted, a package in the Raspbian repositories was added/modified and must now be installed. chromium-browser now depends on this new/modified package:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for jmarbas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  chromium-browser libgl1-mesa-dri pprompt rpi-chromium-mods sonic-pi xserver-xorg-input-all
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

I never got this message before in all my test installations of Raspbian. When it says that chromium-browser is "kept back" it means that there is a package that has been add/modified to the repository that must be installed before the chromium-browser can be updated. So I retried my original command above to see if I can now update chromium-browser and it now works. As you can see below the package "libxcb-image0" is the package that was added/modified:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
[sudo] password for jmarbas:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libxcb-image0
Suggested packages:
  webaccounts-chromium-extension unity-chromium-extension adobe-flashplugin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxcb-image0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  chromium-browser
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 32.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

This question has been strangely resolved itself after I posted it.
I opened the browser and verified that it is now version 56.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before running `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

The current up to date version of Chromium should be 56. If the repositories are not yet updated you could download it [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code)

Comment: Yeah, ofcourse, I always run update before upgrade so that was not the problem.

However a strange thing happened after I posted my question. I got a new message saying that chromium-browser was "kept back"  when I tried to upgrade. This means that a package was added/updated after I asked my question. It can now be installed if I also install this new package. See edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think Chromium is based on chrome, but it isn't supported by Google.  Basically, whoever created Chromium has to update it.

Chromium (current version) uses an older version of chrome.  Yet Chromium is still up to date.

Comment: I recenty got the message that the chromium-browser was "kept back" which means that recenty a package named "libxcb-image0" was introduced/updated in the repositories which chromium-browser depends on. I can now update it. I've updated my question above to show what happened.